# Car Collision Return Force - 3D Car Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

As per my game requirements, I was giving manual force when two cars collide with each other and move back.
So I want the correct code that can justify this. Here is the example, collision response that I want to get:

[image]

As per my understanding, I have written this code:

```
 Vector3 reboundDirection = Vector3.Normalize(transform.position - other.transform.position);
    reboundDirection.y = 0f;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        myRigidbody.AddForce(reboundDirection * 100f, ForceMode.Force);
        appliedSpeed = speed * 0.5f;
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        i++;
    }
```

I am moving, my cars using this code:

```
    //Move the player forward       
    appliedSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 7f;
    appliedSpeed = Mathf.Min(appliedSpeed, speed);
    myRigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * appliedSpeed;
```

Still, as per my observation, I was not getting, collision response in the proper direction. What is the correct way for getting above image reference collision response?

Comment: I do not understand why do you have to apply the force yourself if the cars have a rigidbody? Also if you want to apply the force yourself, how do you neglect the force applied by Unity because of collision. What is the direction of response are you getting in these scenarios? Grom what i have seen yellow car must go to the upper right hand side of the image in left image. Is not this the case?

Comment: Another problem is you are using positions for calculating the direction and positions are from the pivot(which is usually center of the mesh) of your object therefore you will not get a direction upwards in the first image. You will get a direction towards upper left in left image.

Comment: I was looking for manual force because constantly I was applying velocity to give its a continuous movement. So when two cars collision there is no bounce back. So I require to apply something manually. I was working on this kind of game - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bumper.io+game

Comment: Well the problem is those objects in bumber,io are spherical and that makes sense to calculate direction from the center. But you have cars which is rectangular and you can not apply same logic as i said in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you clarify why you have use manual forces or how you handle forces generated by Unity Engine i would like to stress one problem in your approach. You calculate direction based on positions but positions are the center of your cars. Therefore, you are not getting a correct direction as you can see from the image below:

[image]

You calculate the direction between two pivot or center points therefore, your force is a bit tilted in left image. Instead of this you can use [ContactPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint.html) and then calculate the direction.

As more detailed information so that OP can understand what i said! In the above image you can see the region with blue rectangle. You will get all the contact points for the corresponding region using `Collision.contacts`

[image]
then calculate the center point or centroid like this

```
Vector3 centroid = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
foreach (ContactPoint contact in col.contacts)
    {           
        centroid += contact.point;
    }
    centroid = centroid / col.contacts.Length;
```

This is the center of the rectangle to find the direction you need to find its projection on your car like this:

```
    Vector3 projection = gameObject.transform.position;
    projection.x = centroid.x;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce((projection - centroid  )*100, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Since i do not know your set up i just got y and z values from car's position but x value from `centroid` therefore you get a straight blue line not an arrow tilted to left like in first image even in the case two of second image. I hope i am being clear.

Comment: Something like this way, you are saying: Vector3 reboundDirection = transform.position - other.contacts[0].point;

Comment: `other.contact[0].point` is the first contact point. If i were you i would get the centroid of those points by traversing over points adding them and dividing result to number of contact points. However, still it can cause problems if the half of the red car hits the yellow car you again have same issue and i am not sure how you can solve that.

Comment: At present, I expect something simple and easy to understand logic, can you able to write a small code for me ?? Because in words, I can't able to get you exactly what you are trying to say!!!

Comment: It looks some sort of artificial but I want to set up collision response as like reference game.

Comment: I edited my answer but please if you want to do a game like reference game which is mainly relying on physics check out the underlying physics and vector principles first.